# Silent Compile Error - Third Party Dependency

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm having a silent compile-time error while trying to incorporate a third party library into my app. I have followed all the steps to add the library to my app, and it appears to be working (No red lines, no errors, looks good to run). But as soon as I hit run, it throws errors saying `error: package me.iwf.photopicker does not exist`and `error: package me.iwf.photopicker.utils does not exist`. Here are my files:

**PhotoPicker (Third party Library) build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


android {
  compileSdkVersion 22
  buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}


dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
  compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
}
```

**App build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "projects.noteapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

**Settings.gradle**

```
include ':app', ':libs:photopicker'
```

If you need any more info, just comment and ill post it.

If its important, the library I' using is this one:

https://github.com/donglua/PhotoPicker

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

For anybody with the same problem, I had to add `compile project(':libs:photopicker')` to the App build.gradle file.